# JUnit on IntelliJ not working

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

I tried setting up JUnit 5 on my INtelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2. The jar was downloaded but I am getting **Cannot resolve symbol *Assertions*** on importing

> import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guxva.png)

Comment: Check the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies). See also http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to use the JUnit assertions in a regular app class rather than a test class?

## Delete `<scope>test</scope>`

When a Maven dependency carries a `scope` element with a value of `test`, that means you cannot use that library outside of your test-specific source package/folder.

If you are trying to call JUnit from code in your example project’s `src/main/java/…` folder hierarchy, you will see that error. If you call JUnit from `src/test/java…`, you will see success.

To enable JUnit in the `src/main/java/…` folder hierarchy, delete the `scope` element in your POM dependency. So this:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0-RC1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

…becomes this:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

By the way, note that as of 5.4.0 of JUnit, we can specify the new and very convenient single Maven artifact of [`junit-jupiter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter) which in turn will supply 8 libraries to your project.

Comment: Seems something fundamental is broken in IntelliJ,  deleting .m2/repository also fails, tried junit 4 and 5, its unable to complied code in s/rc/test/java with deps from maven, compiling from maven works so maven is not misconfigured

Comment: @teknopaul (a) By default IntelliJ uses its own bundled copy of Maven. There are settings you may want to set if you want to utilize your external copy of Maven. (b) Be sure to update your version of IntelliJ. Their [*Toolbox*](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) applet makes it easy to update your IntelliJ.

Comment: @teknopaul I suggest you try a new project using the [*Maven Quickstart Archetype*](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/), just to verify your environment. Edit the POM to use the latest version of all its parts. Run the default test in JUnit 4. Then replace the JUnit 4 dependency with  [JUnit 5 Jupiter Aggregator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter) dependency. Update the imports in the default test, and run again.